# HTML + CSS - Header Logo in the Way?

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

So I am trying to make these grids, and it should fit.

- Content = 960px width
- Grid1 = 300px

960/3 = 3 with 60px remainder. so I added 10px margin to each, creating a 20px margin in between each, making it 60px of margin.

Well, it'ss not making 3 columns per row. Look:

- http://gyazo.com/5fd8e890a741a9b7977f5762dd9c8a79

#### Code - CSS

```
.grid1, .grid2, .grid3 {
float: left;
margin: 10px;} 

.grid1 {width:300px;}
```

So I made the width 250px to see, and look now:

- http://gyazo.com/4c76187396d52cfdaa287e3577972fdd

So it looks as if the logo is stretching down (the logo is h1):

#### logo code - CSS

```
h1 { font-size: 48px; }
.orangeText {
color: #d5a72b;
}

.bigShadow { text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000; }
.logo { float: left; }
```

Comment: Use a clearfix on the header http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Thanks bro! Worked great!

Comment: @Oliver if you answer could you post this as an "answer" instead of a comment?